# XAML ComboBox items being cropped vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox in which the text of the items when in "drop-down mode" is being cropped at the top and bottom, like this:
[image: ComboBox with cropped text]

I've tried all kinds of combinations of values for the Height, FontSize and VerticalContentAlignment properties, but it insists on putting lots of whitespace above and below each item and then cropping the text, as you can see. Ideally I'd like to reduce or eliminate this whitespace so that the text remains the same size (or just slightly smaller) than the text in the other grid items. I want the combo box to be the same height as a grid cell when not in drop-down mode, so making the combo box itself taller to give the items within it more room is not a good solution.

Here's the relevant bit of my XAML code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:PointTimeRoute}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label Content="{Binding PTTime, Converter={StaticResource TimespanFormatter}}" Height="20" FontSize="11" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"></Label>
            <Label Content="{Binding PTLoc}" Height="20" FontSize="11" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextEditor">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TimeSpan, Converter={StaticResource TimespanFormatter}}" Height="20" FontSize="11" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboEditor">
        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding PointTimeRoute}" ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FromToDutyFilter}}" Height="20" FontSize="11" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Note: "TimespanFormatter" is defined in Application.Resources and doesn't contain any settings for Height, FontSize or any other properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels have Height="20", FontSize="11" *and* Padding="5" (5 is default value for Label). It results in not enough space for text. Set smaller padding or use TextBlocks for example

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it. I couldn't find any reference to "Padding" in the XAML documentation I had.